# Get the values from dataset in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I am first time coding with vb.net and wanted to read values from dataset.

For that i have coded as follows, but not working:

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        '------------------------------Load Name------------------'

        Try
            Dim strcon As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnStringDb").ConnectionString
            Dim i As Integer
            Dim con As New SqlConnection(strcon)

            da = New SqlDataAdapter("select empName from empMaster_VB", con)
            ds = New DataSet()
            da.Fill(ds)
            For(i=0;i<ds.



        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
  End Sub
```

as we take values from dataset in C# i tried it with VB (From for loop) as,

```
for(int i=0;i<ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;i++)
{

  int someVar=int.parse(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].toString());

}
```

but its not working in vb.net as i coded above,,

Please help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
    Dim someVar As Integer = Integer.parse(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(0).toString())
Next
```

You can use [online converter](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/?batchId=91a7eeb4-8edb-4a17-b94a-e580a6472ce0) to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
dim strDay As String
strDay = dsDataSet.dtDataTable.Rows(intRowIndex).ToString
```