# VB.net How do i make questions adjust difficulty based on the marks a student gets on my quiz

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I need help on how to adjust difficulty of questions based on the marks the student gets when attempting the quiz. The problem is I don't know how to access the column with the difficulty in my database using this code. I have already assigned each question to a difficulty as shown in my database below I just don't know with the sql format I've used how to pull it off.

For some reason stack overflow isn't letting me post pictures of the database. I'm using Microsoft Access. The questions are in the first column, answers in second, Question number third and Difficulty fourth. Difficulties are: Easy, Medium and Hard

Below is the code and the database (questions are a draft in the database). I hope someone can help me. Thanks!

```
Public Class frmHigherAlgebra
    Dim inc As Integer
    Dim MaxRows As Integer
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim com As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim dr As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim sql As String
    Dim Questions As String
    Dim Answer As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer
    Public Score As Integer = 0
    Public HighScore As Integer
    Public q_num As Integer = 0
    Public q_num1 As Boolean
    Public q_num2 As Boolean
    Public q_num3 As Boolean
    Public q_num4 As Boolean
    Public q_num5 As Boolean
    Public q_num6 As Boolean
    Public q_num7 As Boolean
    Public q_num8 As Boolean
    Public q_num9 As Boolean
    Public q_num10 As Boolean

    Public Sub LoadQuestions()
        con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=QuizQuestions.accdb"
        con.Open()

        sql = "SELECT * from Algebra ORDER BY RND(-Timer() * [QuestionNumber]) ASC"
        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
        da.Fill(ds, "QuizQuestions")

        con.Close()
        MaxRows = ds.Tables("QuizQuestions").Rows.Count
        inc = -1
    End Sub

    Public Sub NavigateRecords()
        Algebratxt.Text = ds.Tables("QuizQuestions").Rows(inc).Item("Question")
    End Sub

    Public Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBack.Click
        frmHigherNormalquiz.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub

    Public Sub btnNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
        Answer = False
        If inc <> MaxRows - 1 Then

            inc = inc + 1
            NavigateRecords()
            q_num += 1
            txtq_num.Text = "Question" & q_num
        Else
            MsgBox("No more questions.")
        End If
        Algebraanstxt.Clear()
        Algebraanstxt.BackColor = Color.White
    End Sub
    Public Sub btnPrevious_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrevious.Click
        If inc > 0 Then
            inc = inc - 1
            NavigateRecords()
            q_num -= 1
            txtq_num.Text = "Question" & q_num
        ElseIf inc = -1 Then
            MsgBox("No Records Yet")
        ElseIf inc = 0 Then
            MsgBox("No Questions Prior To This")
        End If
        Algebraanstxt.Clear()
    End Sub

    Public Sub btnMark_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMark.Click
        If txtq_num.Text = "Question1" And Answer = True Then
            Score -= 1
            AlgebraProgress.Value -= 1
            MsgBox("You've been awarded the maximum marks on this question")
        End If

        If txtq_num.Text = "Question2" And Answer = True Then
            Score -= 1
            AlgebraProgress.Value -= 1
            MsgBox("You've been awarded the maximum marks on this question")
        End If

        If txtq_num.Text = "Question3" And Answer = True Then
            Score -= 1
            AlgebraProgress.Value -= 1
            MsgBox("You've been awarded the maximum marks on this question")
        End If

        If txtq_num.Text = "Question4" And Answer = True Then
            Score -= 1
            AlgebraProgress.Value -= 1
            MsgBox("You've been awarded the maximum marks on this question")
        End If

        If txtq_num.Text = "Question5" And Answer = True Then
            Score -= 1
            AlgebraProgress.Value -= 1
            MsgBox("You've been awarded the maximum marks on this question")
        End If

        If txtq_num.Text = "Question6" And Answer = True Then
            Score -= 1
            AlgebraProgress.Value -= 1
            MsgBox("You've been awarded the maximum marks on this question")
        End If

        If txtq_num.Text = "Question7" And Answer = True Then
            Score -= 1
            AlgebraProgress.Value -= 1
            MsgBox("You've been awarded the maximum marks on this question")
        End If

        If txtq_num.Text = "Question8" And Answer = True Then
            Score -= 1
            AlgebraProgress.Value -= 1
            MsgBox("You've been awarded the maximum marks on this question")
        End If

        If txtq_num.Text = "Question9" And Answer = True Then
            Score -= 1
            AlgebraProgress.Value -= 1
            MsgBox("You've been awarded the maximum marks on this question")
        End If

        If txtq_num.Text = "Question10" And Answer = True Then
            Score -= 1
            AlgebraProgress.Value -= 1
            MsgBox("You've been awarded the maximum marks on this question")
            Exit Sub
        End If

        Answer = True
        If Algebraanstxt.Text = ds.Tables("QuizQuestions").Rows(inc).Item("Answer") Then
            Score += 1
            txtAlgebraScore.Text = "Score:" & Score
            Algebraanstxt.BackColor = Color.Lime
            AlgebraProgress.Value += 1
            MsgBox("Correct Answer")
        Else
            Algebraanstxt.BackColor = Color.DarkRed
            MsgBox("Incorrect Answer")
            Answer = False
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If Score > HighScore Then
            HighScore = Score
            txtAlgebraHighScore.Text = "High Score:" & HighScore
        End If

        If txtq_num.Text = "Question1" Then
            q_num1 = True
        End If
        If txtq_num.Text = "Question2" Then
            q_num2 = True
        End If
        If txtq_num.Text = "Question3" Then
            q_num3 = True
        End If
        If txtq_num.Text = "Question4" Then
            q_num4 = True
        End If
        If txtq_num.Text = "Question5" Then
            q_num5 = True
        End If
        If txtq_num.Text = "Question6" Then
            q_num6 = True
        End If
        If txtq_num.Text = "Question7" Then
            q_num7 = True
        End If
        If txtq_num.Text = "Question8" Then
            q_num8 = True
        End If
        If txtq_num.Text = "Question9" Then
            q_num9 = True
        End If
        If txtq_num.Text = "Question10" Then
            q_num10 = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
        txtAlgebraScore.Text = "Score:" & Score
        frmHigherAlgebraSummary.Show()
        Close()
        Algebraanstxt.Clear()
        Algebratxt.Clear()
        q_num = 0
        txtq_num.Text = ""
        Algebraanstxt.BackColor = Color.White

    End Sub

    Private Sub frmHigherAlgebra_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
        txtAlgebraScore.Text = "Score:" & Score
        txtAlgebraHighScore.Text = "High Score:" & HighScore

        LoadQuestions()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You have repeated the same code ten times over and over again. Never heard about arrays and loops? See [Arrays in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/).

Comment: Should post data as text table, not image.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the values from dataset in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17647723/get-the-values-from-dataset-in-vb-net)

Comment: You use ds variable without first setting it.

Comment: Why didn't you incorporate the advice given in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70351388/832052)?

Comment: You probably need to do some reviewing and readying up on Access Queries.  I believe what you're asking for here is adding "Where" conational to your select statement so your can select the questions that match the difficulty you're requiring

Comment: @Hursey that is exactly what im asking i just dont know what the code would look like when i inclued "Where" i tried it before but i didnt get the hang of it

Comment: @djv Im not the best with vb so i didnt really understand how to do what was reccomended. If u can break it down into simpler terms for me to understand

Comment: Why are half of your variables and most of your methods Public?